# Option to create channel from Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Is there any option to create a channel dynamically via Composer ??

This is similar to creating channels via SDK code. I am unable to find the documents in the composer tutorial site.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited rsp:) I fully endorse what david_k above has written firstly.  The method`getNativeAPI()` in Composer client, enables access to the Fabric client API from `composer-client` after connecting to an existing business network. That is, Composer client APIs (admin connection and business network connection specifically) offer access to the underlying Fabric client API: eg. calling client API method to read channel info : `getChannel` :

```
const bnc = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
await bnc.connect('admin @sample-network');
const fc = bnc.getNativeAPI();
const channel = fc.getChannel('defaultchannel');
const info = await channel.queryInfo();
console.log('block height', info.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Composer is not about creating and managing a hyperledger fabric network. It is a business network framework that utilises a pre-defined fabric network and requires an already created channel, so will not provide these kinds of hyperledger fabric admin capabilities. As you correctly state the fabric node sdk provides the ability to provide that kind of administrative capability and so that is the API you should use to perform those kind of activities, such as creating channels, joining peers to channels or configuration updates. 
As Paul states, it is possible to gain access to the underlying fabric node sdk client instance which it is currently using to interact with the fabric network, but that does require an already existing business network and as such interacting with the node sdk via this route may not be applicable.

Comment: If I want my application to create a channel at runtime, it is not possible to add via composer. I think, this feature is really helpful for anyone to create private transactions . Can we expect it in upcoming releases??

Comment: You should use the fabric node sdk to do channel creation, it isn't something the composer sdk will look to provide.